# Computer vision: tracking a coin flip

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

Is it possible to write a program that can track and predict the flip of a coin?

The input would be the feed of two or more webcams that monitor the initial few seconds of the flip. The program would analyse the motion of the spinning coin using a physics equation I imagine. The output would be an estimate of whether the coin is going to land heads up or tails up before the event has actually occurred. What languages and libraries would be best suited to this task if it is indeed possible? Are C++ and OpenCV up to the task?

Comment: Yes, C++ and OpenCV are up to the task, but since you're asking this question, I wonder whether *you* are. This is a project for somebody with at least a little experience with computer vision already. I've even seen a full paper on exactly this. You should start smaller, with object tracking for instance.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure this is possible. And I expect OpenCV and a sufficiently powerful system would work. Of course, there are some challenges: following the coin if it's thrown quite high can be difficult, since you need a wide-angle lens (or a camera that moves). A wide-angle lens will lead to poor resolution, which won't do you any favours. Good lighting or distinctly different sides would also help.

Comment: @Dave yes absolutely. I don't intend to dive straight into this at all but it is good to have a goal that motivates you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on the Nyquist Limit of sample aliasing.

Basically, You need to determine how many revolutions per second a typical coin toss will exhibit, and use the Nyquist theorem to work out the minimum frame rate that will capture it.

If you can then determine at which frames the coin is flat, which frame it left the hand, which frame it was caught, and what the initial coin face was, you have a good chance at extrapolating that to the catch.  You may be able to do audio processing to help pinpoint the flip and catch events.

You may also be able to use the motion blur within a frame to determine the angular velocity of the coin edge, but you don't know the axis of rotation.  It would be easier to capture cleaner images.  That means a wide aperture lens and/or good lighting to allow a short exposure time, and possibly a high frame rate.

You could possibly sacrifice higher frame rates if you could interleave the frames from multiple cameras.  That requires good external synchronisation.

Comment: Here's a paper where they studied this as an aside: http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/dyn_coin_07.pdf See §5, where they discuss various aspects of image capture.

Comment: (key point: "We found it best to film
at about 600 frames per second")

Comment: Nice paper!  Only skimmed it, but it looks packed with info from people obsessed over a coin toss...  Possibly stemming from multiple coin-toss losses throughout childhood.

Comment: Here's a real intense study...  http://www.math.hu-berlin.de/~synchron/web/publications/papers/PR2008.pdf (Although slightly unnerving that the first item in the list of 71 references is "The Holy Bible, American Standard Version of the Holy Bible, 1901.")